# Circle detection in microscopy images (noisy)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm working on a project where I have to develop an automated microscope. I need an algorithm to be able to identify circles. I was able to get an algorithm that can deal with noise and find circles, but if the experimental setup changes a bit it no longer works with out tweaking the parameters (not what I want).

I have experimented multiple approaches and the one that works most of the time is using CLAHE, then blurring the image. After this I run the result on Hough Circles. I will show an example.  This is the raw data that doesn't work on the current algorithm:

[image: raw data]

After applying the CLAHE I get:

[image: CLAHE image]

The Hough circles can only find one circle:

[image: circle detection]

Another approach is using histogram equalization:

[image: equilize histogram on raw data]

This will give clearer circles but the Hough circles doesn't work at all. Some times I do some gainDivision to remove the background and then only apply the histogram equalization:

[equilize histogram after doing gain division](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGQjU.png)

The histogram equalization always improve contrast so my idea was to switch the CLAHE to this but I'm not being able to.

This site https://fiveko.com/online-tools/hough-circle-detection-demo/ works on every data after histogram equalization.

Can someone provide a way to detect circles in the equilize histogram image? With out it creating random circles in the back ground due to the noise.

Comment: that doesn't look like much signal. why is the picture so low-contrast in the first place? what can you do with the microscope to improve the picture? what are these things we're looking at?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't see a question in your post. Please be explicit, don't leave it to the imagination of your reader what answer you expect to receive.

Comment: This are droplets. Which are very transparent. So this is the almost the best I can get (might improve slightly with some tweaks). So what I need is a way to detect these droplets in a regular way and the histogram equilize usually provide a good contrast but have alot of noise. The hough circles will then create circles that are not there.

Comment: droplets? squished? illuminate sideways. droplets, being round, will reflect the light into the camera, while everything else, either facing the camera or the light, will not.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could do is tweak GaussianBlur and HoughCircles to work for the one eqi-hist image you provided. Hope it is more general than it seems and will help you somehow.

```
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (11, 11), 0)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blur, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20, 
                           param1=180, param2=17, minRadius=2, maxRadius=50)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems to be working in most of my data. how did you come up with the parameters? i used param1=50, param2=30, min and max 0.

Comment: Just trial and error really. I got the idea that blur should be used from opencv docs. So I cranked the blur up as much as possible to eliminate fake circles. At the same time I tried to reduce param2 as much as possible to enable all possible true circles. In the end param2 worked between 15 and 20 so I chose the middle value. And then tuned param1 to its middle value as well, which was between 150 and 220.